# access response in facebook nodejs passport app

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, express, passport-facebook

How can I access the response (in order to set cookies) once I receive a user's Facebook profile information?

```
// the function that contains `profile` does not contain request (cookies)

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: authHost + '/auth/facebook/callback'
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    var cookies = cookie.parse(res.headers.cookie); // <-- how can I access cookies?
}));

// however, this function does have access to cookies

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req,res,done){
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        failureRedirect: '/login.php?failureRedirect=true',
        successRedirect: 'http://localhost/?loggedIn=true'
    });
    var cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie)); // <-- √ request is available
});
```